# Rails, how to sort a collection keeping a specific value at the end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an active record collection of some objects...

```
#<CoverElement:0x00007f87a4d78718
  id: 312,
  title: "Title 1",
  link: "",
  coverable_id: 35001,
  coverable_type: "Article",
  created_at: Thu, 07 May 2020 16:55:00 CEST +02:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 07 May 2020 16:55:00 CEST +02:00,
  cover_id: 4,
  format: "small",
  custom_image: nil,
  position: 2,
  second_title: nil,
  second_title_url: nil>,
 #<CoverElement:0x00007f87a4d6fde8
  id: 313,
  title: "Title 2",
  link: "",
  coverable_id: 35010,
  coverable_type: "Article",
  created_at: Thu, 07 May 2020 16:55:00 CEST +02:00,
  updated_at: Sun, 22 Nov 2020 19:33:39 CET +01:00,
  cover_id: 4,
  format: "horizontal",
  custom_image: nil,
  position: 3,
  second_title: nil,
  second_title_url: nil>
```

For the desktop version of the website I use the position as order, but I need another order for the mobile version.
I need to sort by format and "small" must be the last.

Basically formats can be: "large", "vertical", "horizontal" and "small".

I try with

```
@elements.reorder('format ASC')
```

and it works but of course it keep the order "horizontal", "large", "vertical" and "small"

Every object with "small" as format must be at the end. Is there a way to do this or I have to write a custom sort method?

Answer (score 0):

you will need another sort method for the mobile version. However if you sort by format, it will do an alphanumeric sort, which will not give you the results you want ("small" is last).

There are a couple of ways to get the order you want:

first way is to recast the format column as an enum, so that the database contains integer values iso strings:

```rb
class CoverElement < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum format: [ :large, :vertical, :horizontal, :small ]
end
```

if this is not possible, you can do it with an sql snippet something like this:

```rb
order = <<-ORD.squish
  CASE
    WHEN 'format'='large' THEN 4
    WHEN 'format'='vertical' THEN 3
    WHEN 'format'='horizontal' THEN 2
    WHEN 'format'='small' THEN 1
  END
ORD

CoverElement.order(order)
```